# Django DRF: How to show filtered data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am following a todo tutorial. I have TodoItem's and TodoList and I get them when I go to url `http://localhost:8000/api/todos/ . I want to return only completed todoItem's from api. How can I do that

**models.py**

```
class TodoList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="blank title")
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    completed_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), null=True, blank=True)
    #owner = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Todo List"
        verbose_name_plural = "Todo Lists"
        ordering = ["name","created_at", "is_completed", ]

    def __str__(self):
            return self.name


class TodoItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="blank title")
    todo_list = models.ForeignKey(TodoList, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, default="Blank text")
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    completed_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), null=True, blank=True)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), null=True, blank=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Todo List"
        verbose_name_plural = "Todo Lists"
        ordering = ["created_at", "is_completed","deadline","name" ]

    def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *


class TodoItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TodoItem
        fields = '__all__'

class TodoListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TodoList
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import *
from .models import *

class TodoItemView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TodoItemSerializer
    queryset = TodoItem.objects.all()


class TodoListView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TodoListSerializer
    queryset = TodoList.objects.all()
```

And this is the **urls.py** at project level

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include 
from rest_framework import routers
from todo import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'todos', views.TodoView, 'todo')
router.register(r'todoitems', views.TodoListView, 'todoitem')
router.register(r'todolists', views.TodoItemView, 'todolist')


urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),         
        path('api/', include(router.urls))
]
```

Another question is I need a User Login/Registration mechanism. I've added owner property to TodoList (commented out above). But How can list such data like "show me the completed tasks of user1" ?

Comment: @NalinDobhal of course he can do it, but it's not good practice to filter it like that into view you can you use filter class and filter your model by your model fields by using query params

Comment: Have a look at [the filtering documentation page](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/). Also bear in mind that [django_filters](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html) is a separate Python library, which you have to install manually.

Answer (score 1):

Your TodoItemView

```
class TodoItemView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TodoItemSerializer
    queryset = TodoItem.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_class = TodoItemFilter
```

Your TodoItemFilter

```
class TodoItemFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = TodoItem
        fields = ('is_completed',)
```

also you can add other fields of you class 
and in this case you can do http://localhost:8000/api/todos/?is_comploted=true

Comment: should I do that in wiews.py file ?

Comment: put you custom filter into filters.py into this app where you using TodoItem